# Example of a sequence function which is unbounded

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T:X\to X$ be self map on $X$. A map $\phi :X\to[0,\infty)$ is said to be sequence function with respect to $T$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(x_n)<\infty$$ whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(Tx_n,Tx_{n+1})=0.$$ If $\phi:X\to[0,∞)$ is bounded then it is obviously a sequence function but converse need not be true. Please provide me example for this.

Comment: By "map" you mean continuous?

Comment: @msh210: No I just mean it is a function whose domain and co-domain are the same sets.

Comment: I am not sure that it is true then. What if you have some $(Tx_n)$ that is Cauchy, but each element of the sequence is distinct? Then you could define a $\phi:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ where odd terms of $\phi(Tx_n)$ are 0 and even terms are 1. It's bounded but $\ell_{n\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x_n)$ doesn't exist!